# Active Directory user attributes

Tags: active-directory

I need to know length limitations for all Active Directory fields, I can't find it on technet.

Can anyone help me find them?

Thank you!

Comment: Take a look http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find **ALL** AD attributes with **ALL** their details here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If you look at e.g. [`SAM-Account-Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it states:

> **Size**      20 characters or less.